# How can I send a postback to a website?

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this grid from a website:

Obviously this is going to be hard since the grid is paged.  Using firebug, hovering my mouse over one of the numbers will give me this javascript:

```
"javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$CMSGMainContentPlaceHolder$ToolContentPlaceHolder$MCDContentPlaceHolder$ncdControl1$ncdGridView','Page$2')"
```

Is there anyway I can trigger that postback, and get the HTML back?

Edit: The grid is in an update panel, so the url doesn't change when you cycle through the paging.

Comment: The secret is  to mimic what happens after the postback button press  occurs. Use a free package called 'Fiddler' or similiar Firefox browser plugin to examine the data being passed between the browser and the web server then simulate with a GET or POST to the hidden URL where the information is coming from on the site and read what comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
ie.Link(Find.ByUrl("javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select$0')")).Click();
```

Maybe you will have to jump [through some hoops to get the correct ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727963/finding-the-child-of-a-parents-sibling-element-with-watin) for the control.

Comment: This should do just fine.  Thanks for the link!